# Make blank params[] nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, collections

When a user submits a form and leaves certain fields blank, they get saved as blank in the DB.  I would like to iterate through the params[:user] collection (for example) and if a field is blank, set it to nil before updating attributes.  I can't figure out how to do this though as the only way I know to iterate creates new objects:

```
coll = params[:user].each do |c|
    if c == ""
       c = nil
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than waiting until later, why not build this into the logic of the form? As the values are collected, put a check that switches `nil` for any entry containing only whitespace or nothing at all. That way blanks never get into the stored values.

Comment: I think the problem would be that the nil values would then not overwrite the db value.

Comment: Because this is now on first page of google for related search, note to other searchers: there is now a gem which will do this automatically for you - https://github.com/grosser/clear_empty_attributes

Comment: Shouldn't that `ends` in the OP code snippet be `end`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider what you're doing here by using filters in the controller to affect how a model behaves when saved or updated. I think a much cleaner method would be a `before_save` call back in the model or an observer. This way, you're getting the same behavior no matter where the change originates from, whether its via a controller, the console or even when running batch processes.

Example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  NULL_ATTRS = %w( middle_name )
  before_save :nil_if_blank

  protected

  def nil_if_blank
    NULL_ATTRS.each { |attr| self[attr] = nil if self[attr].blank? }
  end
end
```

This yields the expected behavior:

```
>> c = Customer.new
=> #<Customer id: nil, first_name: nil, middle_name: nil, last_name: nil>
>> c.first_name = "Matt"
=> "Matt"
>> c.middle_name = "" # blank string here
=> ""
>> c.last_name = "Haley"
=> "Haley"
>> c.save
=> true
>> c.middle_name.nil?
=> true
>>
```

Comment: "before_save :blank_if_nil" should be "before_save :nil_if_blank".  I like this approach the best so far, with the code pushed into the model.

Comment: Somewhat new to Ruby/Rails, but wouldn't wouldn't before_validate be better than before_save here?

Comment: The only problem i see with this is that the callback will be called every time a model is validated (or saved), and it will have to iterate over all the same attributes regardless of the context.  For example, there may be one controller action affecting on set of attributes, and another affecting another set.  I think this callbacks should somehow be attached to individual parameters, like validations are.

Comment: In mvc, it is part of the controller's role to mediate input. The model should not manipulate values passed to a create/update function, only accept or reject through validation.

Comment: Remember to also update existing data in the database (on development, staging and production) by running this in the respective consoles: `Customer.all.each do |c| c.save end`

Comment: Here's a mini-framework based on this, so it can be applied to all model classes: https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/dbd33b0a34ff21cc8787

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to kill the blanks, you can just do `params.delete_if {|k,v| v.blank?}`.

Comment: Careful with this. If you're using update_attributes, and you have fields which are allowed to be blank, the user will never be able to clear those fields if you remove them from the params hash.

Comment: thank you. so many answers based on engineering when simple programming will do the trick. filters, callbacks, observers, all super awesome things. but when one simple line of ruby code works perfectly, why not use it? btw @jdl, this can be tightened like I did in order to handle password fields in rails 3.1... params[:user].delete_if {|k,v| /.*password.*/.match(k) && v.blank?} Can anyone say DRY KISS?

Comment: To address @jdl's concern, make the params you want to kill explicit in the condition: `params.delete_if {|k,v| %w(killme1 killme2).include?(k) and v.blank?}`

Comment: Also this won't handle nested params, which is how form values get submitted

Comment: He will end never erasing a field when using `update`.

Comment: also `false.blank?` => true

Answer (score 5):

A good gem for handling this in the model: https://github.com/rmm5t/strip_attributes

It defines a `before_validation` hook that trims whitespaces and sets empty strings to nil.

Answer (score 4):

In the ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def nilify(p)
    p.transform_values!{|v| v.present? ? v : nil }
  end

end
```

In your controller, modify the strong parameters filter method to call nilify:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def user_params
    nilify params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using inject, which is obvious as to what is happening.

```
params = params.inject({}){|new_params, kv| 
  new_params[kv[0]] = kv[1].blank? ? nil : kv[1]
  new_params
}
```

There is also a hack you can do with merge by merging with itself, and passing a block to handle the new value (although this isn't really the intended use for it, but it is more concise)

```
params.merge(params){|k, v| v.blank? ? nil : v}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would encourage functionality to be moved into the model, as stated in other answers this means that you will get the same behavior no matter where the change originates from.

However, I don't think in this case it is correct. The affect being noticed is purely down to not being able to encode the difference between a blank string and nil value in the HTTP request. For this reason it should be remedied at the controller level. It also means that in other places it is still possible to store an empty string in the model (which there could be for a legitimate reason for, and if not it is simple to cover with standard validations).

The code I'm using to overcome this problem is:

```
# application_controller.rb
...

def clean_params
  @clean_params ||= HashWithIndifferentAccess.new.merge blank_to_nil( params )
end

def blank_to_nil(hash)
  hash.inject({}){|h,(k,v)|
    h.merge(
      k => case v
      when Hash  : blank_to_nil v
      when Array : v.map{|e| e.is_a?( Hash ) ? blank_to_nil(e) : e}
      else v == "" ? nil : v
      end
    )
  }
end

...
```

I've tried to keep the code as concise as possible, although readability has suffered somewhat, so here is a test case to demonstrate its functionality:

```
require "test/unit"
class BlankToNilTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def blank_to_nil(hash)
    hash.inject({}){|h,(k,v)|
      h.merge(
        k => case v
        when Hash  : blank_to_nil v
        when Array : v.map{|e| e.is_a?( Hash ) ? blank_to_nil(e) : e}
        else v == "" ? nil : v
        end
      )
    }
  end

  def test_should_convert_blanks_to_nil
    hash =        {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => ""}
    assert_equal( {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => nil}, blank_to_nil(hash) )
  end

  def test_should_leave_empty_hashes_intact
    hash =        {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => {}}
    assert_equal( {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => {}}, blank_to_nil(hash) )
  end

  def test_should_leave_empty_arrays_intact
    hash =        {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => []}
    assert_equal( {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => []}, blank_to_nil(hash) )
  end

  def test_should_convert_nested_hashes
    hash =        {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => {:d => 2, :e => {:f => "",  :g => "",  :h => 5}, :i => "bar"}}
    assert_equal( {:a => nil, :b => "b", :c => {:d => 2, :e => {:f => nil, :g => nil, :h => 5}, :i => "bar"}}, blank_to_nil(hash) )
  end

  def test_should_convert_nested_hashes_in_arrays
    hash =        {:book_attributes => [{:name => "b", :isbn => "" },{:name => "c", :isbn => "" }], :shelf_id => 2}
    assert_equal( {:book_attributes => [{:name => "b", :isbn => nil},{:name => "c", :isbn => nil}], :shelf_id => 2}, blank_to_nil(hash))
  end

  def test_should_leave_arrays_not_containing_hashes_intact
    hash =        {:as => ["", nil, "foobar"]}
    assert_equal( {:as => ["", nil, "foobar"]}, blank_to_nil(hash))
  end

  def test_should_work_with_mad_combination_of_arrays_and_hashes
    hash =        {:as => ["", nil, "foobar", {:b => "b", :c => "",  :d => nil, :e => [1,2,3,{:a => "" }]}]}
    assert_equal( {:as => ["", nil, "foobar", {:b => "b", :c => nil, :d => nil, :e => [1,2,3,{:a => nil}]}]}, blank_to_nil(hash))
  end

end
```

This can then be used in a controller like so:

```
...
@book.update_attributes(clean_params[:book])
...
```

Answer (score 2):

before_save seems like the wrong location to me, what if you want to use the value before saving. So I overrode the setters instead:

```
# include through module or define under active_record
def self.nil_if_blank(*args)
  args.each do |att|
    define_method att.to_s + '=' do |val|
      val = nil if val.respond_to?(:empty?) && val.empty?
      super(val)
    end
  end
end

#inside model
nil_if_blank :attr1, :attr2
```

---

Just to be complete I put the following in lib/my_model_extensions.rb

```
module MyModelExtensions
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.nil_if_blank(*args)
        args.each do |att|
          define_method att.to_s + '=' do |val|
            val = nil if val.respond_to?(:empty?) && val.empty?
            super(val)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and use it like this:

```
class MyModel
  include MyModelExtensions
  nil_if_blank :attr1, :attr2
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *[attribute_normalizer](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer)* gem and use the *blank* normalizer that will transform empty strings in nil values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "in place" collect method (also known as map!)

```
params[:user].collect! {|c| c == "" ? nil : c}
```

Comment: Tried this with Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3p0. Any idea why this would give `undefined method 'collect!' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x9fec190>`? Just noticed that this thread is 3 years old.  Is there a better way now?

Comment: That is a [Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), not an Array -- hashes don't understand `collect`

Comment: Okay, then I guess I don't understand your original answer. Isn't `params[:user]` the hash of parameters passed to the UsersController?

Comment: This suffers from the same limitation as mentioned by jdl in the comment to Chuck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chris,

Here is a recursive parsing of params that have blanc values.

```
before_filter :process_params

......



private
def process_params
....
  set_blanc_values_to_nil(params)
end

# Maybe move method to ApplicationController
# recursively sets all blanc values to nil
def set_blanc_values_to_nil!(my_hash)
    my_hash.keys.each do |key|
        val = my_hash[key]
        next if val.nil?
        my_hash[key] = nil if val.is_a?(String) && val.empty?
        set_blanc_values_to_nil!(val) if val.is_a? Hash
    end
end
```

Comment: Chris,

Please also notice that it is not good to do something like:

container.each{||
... #modifying container here
}

if you plan to delete/add elements in container (not the case in here, but just keep that in mind)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a shorter version that ensures being able to clear attributes that were previously set (i.e. does not remove attributes that have blank values from the params hash).

```rb
params.require(:user).permit(:some, :attributes).transform_values(&:presence)
```

This relies on the `Object#presence` method provided by ActiveSupport which returns the object if `present?` is true and otherwise returns `nil`.

I would very much recommend doing this in the controller as to not introduce unexpected behavior for other code working directly with the model.

Answer (score 0):

I generalized an answer and made a hook/extension that can be used as an initializer. This allows it to be used across multiple models. I've added it as part of my [ActiveRecordHelpers repo on GitHub](https://github.com/svargo/active-record-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
def remove_empty_params(param, key)
  param[key] = param[key].reject { |c| c.empty? }
end
```

and call it with

```
remove_empty_params(params[:shipments], :included_clients)
```

No need to get super tricky in the model. And this way you can control which params get cleaned up.

```
params = {
      "shipments"=>{
        "included_clients" => ["", "4"]
      }
    }
```

will turn into

```
>> params["shipments"]
=> {"included_clients" => ["4"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which attributes you want to encode blanks as nils for you can use the following attribute setter override:

```
def colour=(colour)
  super(colour.blank? ? nil : colour)
end
```

A bit bulky if you have a lot of attributes to cover though.

Answer (score 0):

## Rails 6.1+ Answer with `compact_blank`

The [`compact_blank method`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact) will do this exactly what you're looking for. For example:

```rb
def user_params
  # removes first_name, middle_name, last_name if blank (i.e. '')
  params.require(:user).compact_blank.permit('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name')
end
```

If the user leaves the middle_name field empty, Rails forms will generate params as: `{ user: { first_name: 'Bob', middle_name '', last_name: 'Loblaw' }}`. By default, this adds an empty string into your database for `middle_name`, instead of `null`. Not what we generally want.

The `compact_blank` method as shown above will remove the `middle_name` from params since it's blank. It removes [blank values](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) from params, such as empty strings (full list: `nil`, '', ' ', [], {}, and `false`).

### Example form for User

```rb
# users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= f.submit "Create User" %>
<% end %>
```

Using the above form along with the `user_params` method will remove any fields left blank by the user so that they're saved to the database as `null`.