# Ruby on Rails: Is there a way to make blank form inputs submit nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make blank params[] nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183506/make-blank-params-nil)

Is there a way to make blank form inputs submit nil? Right now, I'm going through and in a before_save manually converting all "" into nil.

This really doesn't seem very DRY, and I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: Why do you need to make them nil? The absence of them in the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statement should make them `NULL` in the table row. Accessing a non-existant index from a hash (like `params`) would return nil. What else do you need?

Comment: With blank he means the empty string, "".
This will in many cases save in the DB as the empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [attribute_normalizer](http://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of "submitting nil" from a browser.

If field of name 'foo' is not submitted, then if you ask for params[:foo], it will return nil, which seems to be the behavior you desire.

Can you explain more what you want to do?